# Do we need the Stack Overflow mobile app if we have the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: discussion, mobile-app

On the Stack Overflow mobile app I couldn’t figure out how to award an answer, but I was able to do it on the Stack Exchange mobile app.

Thus, I had a better experience with the Stack Exchange app over the Stack Overflow app. Are there any benefits to having both apps? Can I do everything on the Stack Exchange app that I can do on the Stack Overflow app? I’d also like for the Stack Overflow app to add the functionality of awarding answers. I think that may be a bug.

Comment: [strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/839601)

Comment: The bug where you could not accept an answer was reported and fixed months ago [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349270/6083675). Are you still experiencing this bug with the latest version of the app?

Comment: Yes I still can’t find the button.